# How to save layout settings of MFC application?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I understand there are functions that can easily write windows registry, however I found out that in new MFC project created with wizard, some information (like split bar position, visibility of controls) gets stored automatically (or at least I found no CWinApp::Write* calls in the project). Since I have also older projects that don't have this behaviour I need to figure out how to make this without help of project wizard. Would anyone please know how does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MFC control state saving magic happens in the 'New' [MFC Feature Pack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984556(v=vs.90).aspx), specifically in the `SaveState` methods, for example [CMFCToolBar::SaveState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984161.aspx).

To take advantage of this you'll therefore need to upgrade your Toolbars and Menus to use the newer controls and upgrade your application to inherit from [CWinAppEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983877.aspx). I recommend that you use a New MFC Wizard based app as a guide on how to upgrade your old MFC app.

Most of the information is saved in CPane::SaveState(), thus if you want state of some component saved, you need to use classes derived from CPane. (for more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws8s10w4.aspx) is the class hierarchy).

The process of saving window states is initiated through CFrameImpl::OnClosingMainFrame(). This function in turn calls CWinAppEx::SaveState() which saves some application settings and then ALL instances of CMFCToolBar (they add themselves to global list of CMFCToolBars in call to OnCreate). In a similar way all dockable panes are saved but the list belongs to your main frame. Then positioin and size of your main frame is saved.
CViews and CFrameWnds are somewhat less favored, for what I found and tried out, the only information saved was visibility.

Comment: Hmmm you are right. Kingdom for horse... that would be able to read MFC source codes for me.

Comment: If you want a program to read/understand MFC source try something like Agent Ransack.

Comment: Nah I was just being lazy, I have read it in the end, but thank you :) Can I edit your answer, add some info I found and mark it accepted?

Answer (score 0):

I used that loooong time ago. If I correctly reminds it, you should save the informations you want in a overridden `CWinApp::ExitInstance()` before calling base class method, and you load them in `CWinApp::InitInstance`. Be sure to allow for default values, because at first run, there will be nothing to load, and do not forget to call (or copy) base class.